# ScanDisk (ChkDsk) on shared folders on Virtual Machines: is it needed?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, scan-disk

Scenario:

- **Windows XP SP3** running on **Virtual Machine (VM) guest** (VirtualBox).
- A host's **shared folder**, say `d:\VMSharing`.
- The guest VM has **some file(s) in use** from that shared folder (so he is accesing the partition of the host).
- The guest machine **gets aborted** (intentionally, maybe it hangs, the virtual disk runs out of space... etc) so there is no clean closing (flushing) of the shared partition.

Question:

- ¿Should I perform **scandisk** over `D:` from the host?
- ¿maybe from the guest?
- ¿Or none of them?

Posible reasons to understand this hipothetical case scenario:

- **VMs sometimes crash**. It is supposed the need to check the virtual hard disk of the guest operating system, but what about the shared host's disk(s)?
- A full host's **operating system crash** when a VM guest was running (say, WinXP guest running uTorrent). Is it enough the usual host's scandisk?
- **Learning**.

Note:

- Shared partitions on VirtualBox guests are treated as network shared folders.

Comment: I would scan all the disks. Its not clear at what point the virtual machine hangs. Have you verified it still hangs if there isn't a shared folder?

Comment: It is just a hipothetical case, @Ramhound. Intended to understand the fundamentals of scandisk. I have modified the scenario from "hangs" to "gets aborted".

Comment: definitely use chkdsk on the shared volume (from the host; no reason to get hardware abstraction involved in that process). This may not save the files that were open for write, but it will fix most of the corruption to the filesystem tables. As for whether they are network shared, that has little import to the question at hand.